# Using || operator in "current_page?" function

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to test whether the current page is one of two alternatives. I'm trying to use the || operator in ruby along with `current_page?` but I can't get it working. This is what I'm trying

```
if current_page?(first_path || second_path)
```

It only works with `first_path` and not when I add `second_path`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/current_page), `current_page?(options)` is a function that returns:

> True if the current request URI was generated by the given `options`.

You need to pass it your path to get a `boolean` response. You can only do one at a time but you can then do a boolean operation on the two results.

```
current_page?(first_path) || current_page?(second_path)
```

Comment: works, five mins and I mark this answer as valid thanks.